# Are there known issues with PNG and JPEG images generated on iOS?

Tags: ios, png

I got the brilliant idea to generate the app store screen shots for my app from... and app! This works great, except for the fact that some of the PNG or JPEG images are not recognized as valid screen shots when I try to upload them. I checked with image viewer, and they have the required size, colorspace and pixel density.

Is there perhaps some strange issues with PNG and/or JPEG images generated on iOS?

Comment: Yup. Apple uses a special PNG format which can only be read by iOS (and perhaps Xcode too).

Comment: Apple's PNG format is easy to read. The zlib Flate decoder needs to be initialized differently. It doesn't require much different code from a normal PNG decoder.